# Regular expression for variable routes

Tags: regex

I have the following directory:
***Videos/common/Project/Project01/video.project_01.StatusOK/video.project_01.StatusOK.csproj***

And the *regular expression* that I use to extract only with the **last part of the route** (***video.project_01.StatusOK.csproj***) is the following:

**([\w|.]*)/Project/([\w|.|\s]*)/([\w|.|\s]*)/([\w|.|\s]*)([.]*)**

The problem is that if the route varies, that is if there is a directory before: video.project_01.StatusOK.csproj, for example like this: **Videos/common/Project/Project01/video.project_01.StatusOK/test/video.project_01. StatusOK.csproj**, I would extract ***'test'***.

Let's see if someone can help me with a regular expression for java, always extract the last part which contains the ***'.csproj'***, whatever the route.

Regards, and thank you very much

Comment: what's your programing language

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]+csproj
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dt43Vs/1)

[See JAVA code HERE](https://regex101.com/r/dt43Vs/1/codegen?language=java)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\/)` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by a `/`
- `[^\/]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is not a `/`
- `csproj` - matches `csproj` literally

Answer (score 0):

In case you are unaware, Java 7 introduced NIO2 which brought a new interface `java.nio.file.Path`. You can break up the path to your directory and then use a regular expression on each part of the path.

Oracle's *Java Tutorial* has a section on [Path Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)

(There is also a section on *Regular Expressions*)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep to the `/Project/` in your path, you could try this:

[`.*?/Project/.*?(?<=\/)([\w+. ]+\.csproj)$`](https://regex101.com/r/8MGWvF/1/)

That would match

- match any character zero or more times non greedy `(.*?)`
- match `/Project/`
- match any character zero or more times non greedy `(.*?)`
- positive lookbehind that asserts that what is before is a forward slash `(?<=\/)`
- A capturing group `(` *this will contain your match*
- A character class that will match one or more word characters, dot or whitespace `[\w. ]+` one or more times
- Match .csproj `\.csproj`
- Close the capturing group `)`
- The end of the string `$`